# Event processing for layered images in a canvas

Tags: python, events, timing

I have a canvas that is covered by many...many images.  Most overlap each other sometimes 10 deep.  A simple example is

```py
a1 = self.Canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill="red")
self.Canvas.tag_bind(a1,"<Button-1>",self.eventa1)
b1 = self.Canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill="green")
self.Canvas.tag_bind(b1,"<Button-1>",self.eventb1)
c1 = self.Canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill="blue")
self.Canvas.tag_bind(c1,"<Button-1>",self.eventc1)
```

The top layer shows `blue`.  I click on it and `eventc1` is called as expected.

I was wondering if there is any way when I click on position X, Y to get each event covering that point (red, green and blue layer in this case) to fire the corresponding event for that layer in order top to bottom.

Or can the blue event processing have a way to cause the next lower layer' event to automatically fire. There is no way the blue event knows what it is sitting on top of. 20 years ago, I used GTK+ in C and it allowed an event to return an indication to fire a lower level event or not.

Comment: I am sorry, I am writing a program in Python.  I placed the title Python in the initial list of keywords when submitting this question.  I was using C / GTK+ as an example of what I was looking to do using Python and tkinter.    I am currently using Windows 10 (up to date) and Python 3.7.3

Comment: I assume that since I got no reasonable responses, that I am not able to do this in Python.  Thank you to all that read this and could not come up with a way of doing this.  I guess I should give up and go back to C and GTK.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not look at all like C I must say. Looks more like some slippery slithery language...

In GTK you can customise a widget to your hearts content. GtkDrawingArea is typically used when you want to tinker around UI side too. You can override the event handlers for mouse interaction e.g.: widget_klass->button_press_event, widget_klass->motion_notify_event widget_klass->button_release_event and widget_klass->expose_event. You can make your own signal handlers with g_signal_new and fire off which ever one (or multiple ones thereof) you want according to where the click is in each of your custom event handlers. Make sure to add gtk_widget_add_events(widget, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK|etc...) to enable these events in your classes init function.

Enforcing a strict signal handling order might be a bit more complicated. The signals have the option for G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST etc, and you could get 3 running a strict order this way though there's always the chance that the event loop may receive signals at two different stages. Best would be to fire off the one signal with data provided that would list the functions to call and order in which they need to be invoked.

So yes you can do that in C, though it might be tricky. I'm pretty sure all the bindings don't loose functionality so you should be able to do it in almost any language, but as for all non-c coding, when you want to delve deep, the deobfuscation places you on a slippery slope. If you know how to do it in C, skip the snakes and ladders game and write it in C. If you've got boss/team constraints, port it when done, to make people happy - I believe there is enough consistency across the GTK API bindings that it shouldn't be too much of an issue. But being forced to think in a ladedah mindset of simpleness and being expected to achieve fine detailed complex solutions is just untenable.

Comment: I am sorry, I am writing a program in Python. I placed the title Python in the initial list of keywords when submitting this question. I was using C / GTK+ as an example of what I was looking to do using Python and tkinter. I am currently using Windows 10 (up to date) and Python 3.7.3 – WallyG Jul 31 at 19:56